# Rails Time Zome setting for seed and new method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I use the following setting in my `config/application.rb`

```
config.time_zone = "Taipei"
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

And then, I run rake:db drop,create,migrate,seed

My seed generate data time is right(I check out my database),but when I use the new method like `book.new`, this record's create_at time is wrong, it use the default UTC setting.

what's wrong with my setting?

Comment: One thing to clear how can you say that the `.new` generates UTC time means when you save it in database you are seeing the SQL INSERT command? Please clear this thing or post an example.

Comment: Okay try this once, save the record suppose `Item.new(name: 'myfoo').save!`, now `Item.last.created_at` so this will return the time in your timezone.

Comment: it doesn't work, I use like: book.new, book.name = 'book1', book.save , the time is still wrong.

Comment: I did the same and it worked on `rails 4.2`, did you do `Book.last.created_at`?

Comment: I use 4.2 too, do you mean after save, do Book.last.created_at? if you mean this, I tried(before and after save) and it doesn't work...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86579/discussion-between-john-and-deep).